# VBA Excel 2010 msoFileDialogOpen Path.Open Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a simple function which lets the user select a file using Excel 2010's VBA's msoFileDialogOpen property to select a file. When I run it I get the errror:

> Run-time error '424':
>
> Object required

Here is the offending line:

```
    Path.Open
```

Here is the entire function:

```
Public Sub Function4_FileExplorer()
Dim file As Variant
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding vFileName)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        file = .SelectedItems(1)
        Path = file
    End If
    Path.Open
End With
MsgBox file

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & _
       Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

How should I fix this run-time error? I Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` is a `String` so has no `.Open` method (which you call even if the dialog was dismissed; i.e. when `.Show` returns `false`)

Assuming you want to open the selected workbook (you should add a xls/x/m filter)

```
Dim file As String
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding vFileName)
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then
        file = .SelectedItems(1)
        Workbooks.Open file
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Oh, so is that why this function always loops twice? About the .xls/.xlsm filter: good idea, 99% of the time a good practice, but I am opening machine files: .438, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I adapted this to my code and now the data is pasted. My macro is almost fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you assign string value to the variable `Path` and after that you are trying to call method `Open` on this string:

```
Path.Open
```

String is a primitive value and it doesn't have any methods. You can use it as a parameter for function but you cannot call its own methods, since they don't have any.